# How do I save a php form after submitting through my html page?

Tags: php, html

I have made an html page with forms and tables where I input words and numbers and have submit button. Once I click the submit button it outputs the right information that I inputed into a php file BUT it does not save, have do I save it is my question?
Here is part of my html code where I input the information:

```
<body>
<form action="physical_server_check_list_saved.php" method="post">
<table width="800" align="left">
<th width="800" align="left" colspan="2" bgcolor="#D3D3D3">SERVER INFORMATION</th>
<tr>
<td width="200" align="left">Server name:</td>
<td width="600" align="left"><input type="text" size="100" name="servername"></td
/tr>
tr>
<td width="200" align="left">Contact:</td>
<td width="600" align="left"><input type="text" size="100" name="contact"></td
/tr>
<tr>
<td width="800" align="left" colspan="2">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
```

Here is part of my php code, it is the same format except php code added to the table cells displaying the output:

```
<tr>
<td width="200" align="left">Server name:</td>
<td width="600" align="left">
<?php
$servername = $_POST['servername'];
echo $servername;
?>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="200" align="left">Contact:</td>>
<td width="600" align="left">
<?php
$contact = $_POST['contact'];
echo $contact;
?>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Well, from my view you would need to have a database. If you want your form submission information to persist somewhere. You could just post it to localstorage or sessionstorage but if this is a real world project or a small side app. You should use MySQL generate a db, connect to it with a php connection string and then write your data to one of the tables within.

Comment: (BTW: This got three migrate votes on Unix.SE + 2 to close, which is apparently enough to migrate it. I've tried to quickly clean it up, since we sent it over here. I fixed OP's replacing of angle brackets with square brackets and braces with find & replace... If there is something weird, it may well be from my cleanup, not the OP's code.)

Comment: You need to connect to some sort of database, then store your values in the database and retrieve them when needed.

Answer (score 0):

The question is where do you want to save it to. Every time somebody visits your page, PHP builds the page just for them. In your example, it is taking any POST variables and simply displaying them.

There are many ways that you can store and retrieve data in PHP. Some examples might be writing to a file, storing data as part of a session, or storing your data to a database. Those options are listed in order of how complicated they will be to apply.

Before you store your data, though, you'll want to sanitize it. Even though you have a form, that doesn't stop attackers from sending any random information into those variables, and if they aren't sanitized, then whatever you do with them could potentially allow the attacker to exploit your script. How to sanitize data is a bit beyond the scope of this answer, but for simple data, I typically use something like this, using `preg_replace` to make sure that I only get letters and numbers:

```
$my_sanitized_data = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $my_raw_data);
```

In most modern applications, data is most often written to a database. This isn't too complicated, but setting up the database can be. You might want to check with your web host for instructions. Once you do, you may want to follow a tutorial like the following:

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Once you learn how to write data, you can learn how to read your data, and then you can output that to the screen.

Most likely, in the process, you'll want to learn how to use PHP sessions to track your visitor through the website. This can also be used to save data, and is often used along with the database. For instance, when a visitor arrives, you may let them login. The login is handled through the database as, and then the session saves the user that's logged in, and uses that user id to find the appropriate information in the database from the last time they were logged in. Either way, you may find sessions helpful. Essentially, they are a temporary storage that lasts for a visitor until they leave your site.

Here is an article on using PHP sessions:

https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-sessions.php